# jQuery adding a class doesn't work for specific class name

Tags: jquery

I'm puzzled...

This works:

```
$(this).children().removeClass('fa-square').addClass('fa-check-squarex');
```

Note the x at the end of the class name that's added. Any class name other than `fa-check-square` actually works.

This doesn't:

```
$(this).children().removeClass('fa-square').addClass('fa-check-square');
```

Comment: Can you also post HTML code where you are trying to remove/add class?

Comment: Along with the HTML, perhaps the part of the jQuery / Javascript code that shows what `this` refers to

Comment: I guess the class is being added but nothing happens. Because you are using font-Awsome free version. Plz inspect the element and make sure if the class is added to element?

Comment: I’m using FA Pro. The class is not added, but as indicated when I change the name of the class to anything other than fa-check-square the class is added. So the code works, but just not with that one class name.

Comment: For instance, if I change the name to fa-heart, that class is added and it shows up. Really weird.

Comment: You're going to need to post a [mcve] in your question that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Font Awesome documentation to see if the class you are adding is actually part of the Font awesome library - for example - you might need to use  "fa-check-square" or "fa-check-square-o".

You might also need to check if the icon you are using is within the FA version you are using (**icons in version 5 will not be available if you are using version 4.7.4** or other).

```
$(this).children().removeClass('fa-square').addClass('fa-check-square');
```

or

```
  $(this).children().removeClass('fa-square').addClass('fa-check-square-o');
```

Comment: If I use fa-check-square in plain HMTL on the same page it shows up so it works. And I'm using the latest FA Pro version.